# Apply a Shader on RealityKit Scene

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

Is there a way to apply a full screen shader to a RealityKit scene (Swift/iOS)?

I know I can do this with SCNTechnique in SceneKit/ARSCNView, but I'm dealing with an ARView.

- Is there a way in RealityKit one can apply a vertex/fragment shader?
- or a way to get the rendered scene as a texture?

With an ARSCNView I can apply a shader to run over the output of a scene, just like: https://medium.com/ar-tips-and-tricks/arkit-theory-an-introduction-to-scntechniques-710e024bc91e

But with RealityKit, I'm dealing with an ARView which doesn't have a SCNTechnique property

Thanks :-)

Comment: Hi @Chris! What `full screen shader` do you mean exactly? Environment shader?

Comment: Hi Andy, Anything at the minute, I've been trawling the docs, but can't seem to find a reference to apply ANY shader

Comment: Sorry))) Shader to what? To environment or to a model? What do you mean saying `full screen shader`?

Comment: In a ARSCNView I can apply a SCNTechnique over the full screen, as if I'm dealing with a texture. but in RealityKit, I'm dealing with an ARView

Comment: Ok, I've got it. You need `render passes`, also known as `AOV`s. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scntechnique They are not shaders. They are Render passes like `Point Position` pass, `Normals` pass, `ZDepth` channel pass, `UV` pass, etc. But shaders are `Phong`, `Lambert`, `Blinn`, etc.

Comment: Apologies for using the wrong terminology, is there something similar in ARView?

Comment: Alas @Chris, at the moment No.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### iOS RealityKit

In RealityKit for iOS you can apply not only background environmental `image` but also a HDR image for `image based lighting` (IBL). For applying environmental image use [skybox(:_)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/arview/environment/background/3281889-skybox) type method.

```
func skybox(_ resource: EnvironmentResource) -> ARView.Environment.Background
```

This static method uses `EnvironmentResource` object that contains background data for your scene. You can read about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/environmentresource) and in my [story](https://medium.com/macoclock/realitykit-911-lighting-and-shadows-66f99bcd5219) on Medium.

Also, in RealityKit for iOS you are capable of applying a vertex/fragment shader (via [CustomMaterial](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/custommaterial)) and get the rendered scene as a texture (like you could do in SceneKit+Metal).

To find out how to disable a default environment lighting in ARView read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77332150/realitykit-how-to-disable-default-lighting-in-nonar-arview/77333961#77333961).

#### visionOS RealityKit

Use `RealityRenderer` object to get access to customization of environment image and IBL:

```
RealityRenderer().lighting.resource = try! .load(named: "env")
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76755793/spotlightcomponent-is-unavailable-in-visionos/76761509#76761509), shows you how to enable a custom environment lighting in visionOS app.

Comment: do we still have to make ```folderName.skybox/file.hdr``` I'm adding via 

```let skyboxName = "rooitou_park_1k.hdr" // The .exr or .hdr file```
```let skyboxResource = try! EnvironmentResource.load(named: skyboxName)```
```environment.lighting.resource = skyboxResource```
```environment.background = .skybox(skyboxResource)```

All I got is black background and generic lighting on object :- (

Comment: You can do it Apple's way or your own way – it's up to you. The main thing – it must work. Although, I want to point out that this option is buggy.

Comment: Yeh, just lost my bananas with it. Ended up the name... have to use name, and not name.ext... ehh happy time. thanks you for quick reply!
Is there a way to rotate the ibl? and undo ibl/go back to automatic?

Comment: I cannot see the way to rotate IBL (it's a problem for many 3D engines). You must prepare your HDRI file appropriately.

Comment: My example for `three.js `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64454022/is-it-possible-to-rotate-a-cube-environment-map-180-degrees-around-y-axis/64460378#64460378

Comment: Hmm pretty odd... I imagine its just a matter of matrix4x4 * hdr to give it different transform/use for scene lighting. Pretty much any engine I deal with allow for rotation/scale of hdr/map coordinates. This is gonna be difficult task then as I wanted to match hdr rotation to sun position to simulate better "environment" but preserving more or less similar lighting direction

Comment: Probably, it'll be implemented in RealityKit 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

There's a whole pipeline now for post processing, with CIFilters, SpriteKit or Metal Performance shaders. See this talk: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10075/