# 'SpotLightComponent' is unavailable in visionOS

Tags: swiftui, realitykit, visionos

I am working with RealityKit in Vision OS beta 1 and can't build the light source.
I want to use that light source in the fully immersive space (that has no light source by default).
I tried that code to create the entity with the SpotLightComponent.
I got the error 'SpotLightComponent' is unavailable in visionOS.

```
SpotLightComponent.registerComponent()
        
let entity = Entity()
let lightComponent = SpotLightComponent(
   color: .white,
   intensity: 6740.94,
   innerAngleInDegrees: 45.0,
   outerAngleInDegrees: 60.0,
   attenuationRadius: 10.0
)
entity.components.set(lightComponent)
```

I build that code in the swift package limited to only visionOS platform, and from the app itself. No luck.

```
platforms: [
    .visionOS(.v1)
],
```

I expected the code to be able to build at least because the Apple docs have this component listed as available.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/spotlightcomponent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How to create visionOS lighting in RealityKit

You are right. Even though the official documentation explicitly states that `SpotLightComponent` is supported in visionOS, this is not true. At the moment (25 July 2023) you can use only basic `Image Based Lighting` in visionOS apps. Spot light, omni light and directional light are temporarily (I hope that it's ***temporarily***) inaccessible in visionOS version of RealityKit. Here's an example of how you can implement lighting in your visionOS app (IBL images should be in `.hdr`, `.png`, `.jpg` or `.heic` formats).

[image]

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            
            let model = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.1),
                               materials: [SimpleMaterial()])
            content.add(model)
            
            guard let env = try? await EnvironmentResource(named: "Directional")
            else { return }
            
            var iblComponent = ImageBasedLightComponent(source: .single(env),
                                             intensityExponent: 7.95)

            model.components[ImageBasedLightComponent.self] = iblComponent
            model.components.set(ImageBasedLightReceiverComponent(imageBasedLight: model))
        }
        .frame(depth: 0)
    }
}
```

[image]

My `Directional.png` file dimensions are `1000 x 625` pixels:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will check the solution tomorrow.

Comment: @AndyJazz do you have other examples of IBL that I can reference to try and understand how to better add lighting to my scenes for the full immersion mode?

I have a bunch of lights in Blender, but none of them seem to auto translate to IBL and I'm not sure how/where to start learning about how to convert my Blender lights to IBL for visionOS.

Comment: @mesqueeb, at the moment this is my only post about IBL lighting in visionOS on SO. Formulate your question and I'll try to answer it.

Comment: @AndyJazz I was able to set up a Skybox for my immersive scene. However I have tried many different IBL files/formats, but shadows don't seem to work like they do in Blender Cycles Renderer...
My whole room is illuminated without shadows anywhere.  I will try to post a new forum thread on this soon and let you know, but I thought I'd mention it on beforehand in case you had off the cuff ideas. Cheers!!

Comment: Dear @AndyJazz I've posted my detailed question on how to prep IBL here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/743200
Would greatly benefit from your input!